# Why JSONArray is throwing ClassNotFound Exception from JSP?

Tags: json, jsp, servlets, liferay, portlet

```
Map countryList = new HashMap();
String str = "http://10.10.10.25/TEPortalIntegration/CustomerPortalAppIntegrationService.svc/PaymentSchedule/PEPL/Unit336";
 try {
    URL url = new URL(str);

    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

       BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    urlc.getInputStream()));

    String line, des;
    double title;
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(2048);

    while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
      builder.append(line);
    }

            // convert response to JSON array
    final JSONArray jsa = new JSONArray(builder.toString());

            // extract out data of interest
    for (int i = 0; i < jsa.length(); i++) {
        final JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) jsa.get(i);
        title = jo.getDouble("NetAmount");

        countryList.put(i, title);
    }
    System.out.println(countryList); /* Giving result if i run in Console*/
  } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
  renderRequest.setAttribute("out-string", countryList);
```

The above code is to consume JSON web services from java client. I am able to access it from java console application. But when trying with JSP or Liferay its not working. In JSP its giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray.   Please help me to fix it.
    Should i need to add any more jar files to the libraries to make it working in JSP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the jar file containing `JSONArray` class in your web application as per this directory structure:

```
Tomcat_HOME
  ->
   webapps
     ->
       YourWebAppName
         ->
            WEB-INF
               ->lib
                  ->Here goes your jar file
```

Comment: Can you please tell which are the jar files i need to include? can you please give me downloading link?

Comment: just go to this site and search you will get know which all libraries have this class : http://www.findjar.com

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `json.org.JSONArray`, have you considered using Liferay's JSON API?

You can import:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONArray;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONObject;
```

They do something like:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject(myJSONObjectString);
JSONArray jsonArray = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray(myJSONArrayString);
```

This way there is no additional JAR required!